# Is there a fast way to replace a large tbody in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace a `tbody` with new Html using the jQuery below. The .empty() function hangs when the Html is above 1Mb.

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //$("#myTable tbody").empty();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {

        //$("#myTable tbody").html(data);
        replaceTableBody("thebody", data);

    });
});
```

I'm not worried if it's a tricky solution, I just want it to work...
I tried this but could not get it to work: [replacehtml-for-when-innerhtml-dogs-you-down](http://ajaxian.com/archives/replacehtml-for-when-innerhtml-dogs-you-down).

It only needs to work in IE.

**EDIT**

```
    var replaceTableBody = function(tbodyId, html){
        var temp  = document.createElement('div');
        temp.innerHTML = '<table><tbody id="thebody">'+html;
        var tb = document.getElementById(tbodyId);
        tb.parentNode.replaceChild(temp.firstChild.firstChild, tb);
        temp = null;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done this before. **you must not use jquery** if you want this to be faster.

I wrote a long blog post about this and how its done, its long so i will not paste it here, just link it:

http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2009/08/javascript-insert-table-rows-table-body.html

The reason you must **not use jquery** is that jquery does certain things once you pass text into .html(), like search for scripts, execute them, fix certain things etc. this is usually a good thing, but its not a good thing with **1mb of text on IE**.

Comment: does the original table have a tbody who's id is 'thebody' ?

Comment: yes it does. could it have anything to do with the 'div' it's creating?

Comment: no, that is how you replace a tbody without using jquery on ie. paste your original table html. also what comes back from the ajax request? just <tr> elements i hope?

Comment: Yeah, an unhealthy amount of `<tr>`

Comment: One question though. Why did you include the `<table>` tag in your JS ? I removed it...

Comment: oh you removed the table tag? thats probably why the script is broken. you cant insert a tbody tag into a table with plain javascript. see: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/768185-innerhtml-tbody

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if your first delete all rows of the tbody with something like $('#myTable tbody').remove() and than call $('#myTable tbody').empty()....if the last step is necessaryat all after removing the rows...

Answer (score 0):

try using the .each() and delete each row seperate.

$("tbody tr").each( function() { $(this).remove(); });
I think the jquery is right, but its the basic idea.

Comment: surely that takes even longer than `.empty()` ?

Comment: Normally, but if empty() is hanging cause its to much data, maybe doing it 1 by 1 will not hang.

Answer (score 0):

Per the jQuery API documentation:

`When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.`

Do you have a need to call `empty()` prior to updating the `tbody`?